# Vue: How to use store with component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vuex

//store

```
export default {
  state: {
    aboutModels: []
  },
  actions: {
    findBy: ({commit}, about)=> {
      //do getModels
      var aboutModels = [{name: 'About'}] //Vue.resource('/abouts').get(about)
      commit('setModels', aboutModels)
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getModels(state){
      return state.aboutModels
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setModels: (state, aboutModels)=> {
      state.aboutModels = aboutModels
    }
  }
}
```

//component

```
import {mapActions, mapGetters} from "vuex";

export default {
  name: 'About',
  template: require('./about.template'),
  style: require('./about.style'),
  created () {
    document.title = 'About'
    this.findBy()
  },
  computed: mapGetters({
    abouts: 'getModels'
  }),
  methods: mapActions({
    findBy: 'findBy'
  })
}
```

//view

```
<div class="about" v-for="about in abouts">{{about.name}}</div>
```

//error

```
vue.js:2532[Vue warn]: Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements:
<div class="about" v-for="about in abouts">{{about.name}}</div>

vue.js:2532[Vue warn]: Multiple root nodes returned from render function. Render function should return a single root node. (found in component <About>)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are mapping your Vuex state getters and action correctly. Your problem is something else as your error message states...

In your component template you can not use `v-for` directive on a root element. For example this is not allowed because your component can have multiple root elements:

```
<template>
   <div class="about" v-for="about in abouts">{{about.name}}</div>
</template>
```

instead do it this way:

```
<template>
   <div>
      <div class="about" v-for="about in abouts">{{about.name}}</div>
   </div>
</template>
```

**  *fixed typo in template tag **